# Firefox Hides Login Text Fields

Tags: firefox, https

My institution uses a separate login page for a community ShareLatex account. The page is not secured over https according to Firefox. Normally I can create an exception for these sites through the regular Firefox settings, however, in this case, Firefox actually *hides* the login fields!

Here is a screenshot of the page on Firefox:

[image: Firefox Page]

And here is a screenshot of the same page on Microsoft Edge:

[image: Edge Page]

What's going on?

How can I log in to this page with Firefox?

Comment: Do you use any addons? You may try a fresh profile without addons and changed settings by launching ``firefox -ProfileManager -new-instance`` and creating a second profile.  Can you still reproduce it with a new profile?

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was able to pinpoint which addon was blocking the page elements pretty quickly (an old one I didn't remember). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [web-console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) to find out if Firefox has detected any errors in the HTML, CSS or Javascript on that page.

You can verify that Javascript is enabled in about:config

If you have a plugin/addon/extension that disables Javascript, you should check whether it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was caused by an addon and disabling it solved the issue.

*(adding this here from a question comment as the user is now deleted)*